# FirebaseUser cannot reauthenitcate to delete account

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

As the title suggests I am having trouble deleting a Firebase user. I have 2 sign in types enabled in Firebase console :

- Anonymous
- Google

These providers types are mirrored in the application and signing in is not an issue using `firebase-ui-auth`

```
  listOf(
     IdpConfig.AnonymousBuilder().build(),
     IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build())
```

I want the user to be able to delete their account, this works fine for Anonymous users but fails for Users that signed in with a google account using a `GoogleAuthCredential`. In order to do this the documentation states you need to "reauthenticate" : `FirebaseUser::reauthenticate`.  This is where I am having trouble and re-authentication always fails with :

```
FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException

ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL
       
The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Invalid id_token in IdP response: <token provided in request>, error: id token is not issued by Google. ]
```

I have checked the token is within the UTC expiry time, and my device clock is set correctly.

Current Code (using coroutines):

```
class UserActions internal constructor(
        private val context: Context,
        private val authUI: AuthUI,
        private val auth: FirebaseAuth)  {

    suspend fun signOut(): Boolean = suspendCoroutine { cont -> cont.suspendCompletableTask(authUI.signOut(context)) }

    suspend fun delete(): Boolean {
        auth.currentUser
            ?.takeIf { user -> !user.isAnonymous }
            ?.let { user ->
                val tokenResult: GetTokenResult = suspendCoroutine { cont -> cont.suspendTask(user.getIdToken(true)) }
                val credential : AuthCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(tokenResult.token, null)
                // Point of failure - always returns false with above error.
                val success: Boolean = suspendCoroutine { cont -> cont.suspendCompletableTask(user.reauthenticate(credential)) }
                if (!success) return false
        }

        return suspendCoroutine { cont -> cont.suspendCompletableTask(authUI.delete(context)) }
    }

    private fun <R> Continuation<R>.suspendTask(task: Task<R>) {
        task.addOnSuccessListener { this.success(it) }
            .addOnFailureListener { this.failure(it) }
    }

    private fun Continuation<Boolean>.suspendCompletableTask(task: Task<Void>) {
        task.addOnSuccessListener { this.success() }
            .addOnFailureListener { this.failure() }
    }
    
    private fun Continuation<Boolean>.success() = resume(true)
    private fun Continuation<Boolean>.failure() = resume(false)

    private fun <R> Continuation<R>.success(r : R) = resume(r)
    private fun <R> Continuation<R>.failure(t : Exception) = resumeWithException(t)
}
```

I thought that maybe I had the token incorrectly added as a parameter arguemnt for :

```
GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(tokenResult.token, null)
```

So swapped to :

```
GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(null, tokenResult.token)
```

But said I had an invalid value in the error description so I have the argument correct for the `AuthCredential` and a "valid" id token as far as I can see.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: 1. Clear Cache. :)

Comment: I have already tried clearing cache, re-installing, tried on multiple devices, sign out ./ sign in.  No luck - same result every time when trying to delete an account tied to a GoogleAuthProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : Simple answer to this one in the end.

Both `FirebaseUser` and `GoogleSigInAccount` refer to having a `idToken`.  I was using the former  for the token here :

```
val tokenResult: GetTokenResult = suspendCoroutine { cont -> cont.suspendTask(user.getIdToken(true)) }
val credential : AuthCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(tokenResult.token, null)
```

The `AuthCredential` was now using the incorrect token.  What I should have used was :

```
val token = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context)?.idToken.orEmpty()
val credential : AuthCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(token, null)
```

So the error was correct - I was using the `FirebaseUser` token when reauthenticating a `GoogleAuthCredential` which should be using the `GoogleSigInAccount` token.

### **Update**

As tokens are short lived the above can still fail if the token becomes stale.  the solution is to perform a "silent sign in" to refresh the token.  This **cannot** be done through `FirebaseAuth::silentSignin` as this fails if a `FirebaseUser` is already signed in. It requires a call to `GoogleSignInClient::silentSignIn`.

Revised full code :

```
class UserActions internal constructor(
    private val context: Context,
    private val authUI: AuthUI,
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth) {

    suspend fun signOut(): Boolean = suspendCoroutine { cont -> cont.suspendCompletableTask(authUI.signOut(context)) }

    suspend fun delete(): Boolean {
        auth.currentUser
            ?.takeIf { user -> !user.isAnonymous }
            ?.let { user ->
                val credential: AuthCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(getFreshGoogleIdToken(), null)
                val success: Boolean = suspendCoroutine { cont -> cont.suspendCompletableTask(user.reauthenticate(credential)) }
                if (!success) return false
            }

        return suspendCoroutine { cont -> cont.suspendCompletableTask(authUI.delete(context)) }
    }

    private suspend fun getFreshGoogleIdToken(): String = suspendCoroutine<GoogleSignInAccount> { cont ->
        cont.suspendTask(
            GoogleSignIn.getClient(
                context,
                GoogleSignInOptions.Builder()
                    .requestProfile()
                    .requestId()
                    .requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    .build())
                .silentSignIn())
    }.idToken.orEmpty()

    private fun <R> Continuation<R>.suspendTask(task: Task<R>) {
        task.addOnSuccessListener { this.success(it) }
            .addOnFailureListener { this.failure(it) }
    }

    private fun Continuation<Boolean>.suspendCompletableTask(task: Task<Void>) {
        task.addOnSuccessListener { this.success() }
            .addOnFailureListener { this.failure() }
    }

    private fun Continuation<Boolean>.success() = resume(true)
    private fun Continuation<Boolean>.failure() = resume(false)

    private fun <R> Continuation<R>.success(r: R) = resume(r)
    private fun <R> Continuation<R>.failure(t: Exception) = resumeWithException(t)
}
```